# Python: How do I extract specific bits from a byte?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a message which reads as `14 09 00 79 3d 00 23 27`. I can extract each byte from this message by calling `message[4]`, which will give me `3d` for example. How do I extract the individual 8 bits from this byte? For example, how would I get bits 24-27 as as single message? How about just bit 28?

Comment: so are you asking how to represent a base 16 integer as base 2 in python, or are you asking how to extract certain bits of a number? or both, extract certain bits and display in binary?

Comment: What's the data type of that message? Please provide a Python literal.

Answer (score 46, accepted):

To answer the second part of your question, you can get specific bit values using bitwise operations

```
# getting your message as int
i = int("140900793d002327", 16)

# getting bit at position 28 (counting from 0 from right)
(i >> 28) & 1

# getting bits at position 24-27
bin((i >> 24) & 0b111)
```

Comment: @StefanPochmann Presumably to shift the relevant bits to the start of the integer. `3B 00 00 00` would be more annoying to work with compared to `3B`

Comment: @TemporalWolf That's not what I meant. Check out the updated answer for what I meant.

Comment: @StefanPochmann that he's demonstrating two separate examples?

Comment: @TemporalWolf Huh? That's not what they changed.

Comment: Should be good now. Before I used two bit shifts, when only one is necessary. The reason was first I thought OP wanted the value of the int having a 1 at the position, which would be given by ```i & 1 << 28```. But then I realized it wasn't the case so I added the second bitshift.... which could be merged into one. Clear?

Comment: Thanks for the reply! I didn't quite understand what you mean by `24 & 0b111`, though. `0b111` is 7 in decimal. How did you get 24-27 with that?

Comment: The point is: I want to get the three bits values at positions 24 25 and 26, to do that, so, the idea is to do shift the bits so the positions become 0 1 and 2 and then do an AND operation with a number that has 1 to positions 0 1 2 and 0s elsewhere. I could have just done ```i>>24 & 7```, but I thought it would be clearer to write it in binary.

Comment: Oh that explains it! Thank you so much. :)

If I had to get, say, 30-35, I would `i >> 30 & 0b111111` then? To get bits 30, 31, 32, 33, 34, 35?

Comment: You've got it :)

Comment: So why does `& 1` works like `[1]`?

Comment: What if my hex message has a lot of leading zeros?

Answer (score 5):

The easiest way to do this is to use the & operator. Convert your message to an int using `int(str_msg, 16)`. convert int to binary string using `bin(myint)`

To get bits 4-6 (from left) in a byte:

```
>> msg = int("10110111", 2) # or 0b10110111
>> extractor = int("00011100", 2) # or 0b10110111
>> result = msg & extractor
>> print bin(result)
00010100
```

If you want, you can bit shift result using `result >> 2`. Obviously you will want to make this more dynamic but this is a dumbed down example.

Comment: Its probably easier to put in 28 in base 2 than base 10. With `0b11100` it's much clearer which bits you want

Comment: Not sure whether the new version is better or even worse than the old version. Why not use what @jacoblaw showed?

Comment: I'ts just an example. The person wasn't asking how to get the input, just the result. How he gets the input is up to him. I'm sure he already knows that.

Comment: @IanKirkpatrick I'm just mentioning it because it seems like you didn't know about this way of entering binary in python, sorry if that's not the case I don't mean to offend you. But what I meant was not converting a string representation of the binary into an integer, but to do `msg = 0b10110111`. You can do a similar thing with hex, `test = 0xFF` for example. In some cases this makes code easier to understand

Comment: @jacoblaw That `int("...", 2)` way is also less efficient, as that's a run-time calculation rather than compile-time. Might not matter, but still. It's just all-around worse.