# Python read bits from bytes in an elf file

Tags: python, byte, bit, elf

I would like to read some bits in an elf file in Python. I have found an elf file parser which locates the section. I looked into using seek to read, but the data read out are in bytes.
For example: in the desired section in my elf file I have `20  14  52  10  01  DA  1E  98  00  CD  EF  0F  00  00  00  00` in hex, and I need to read bits `0-3, 4-6, 26-27`.

What would be the best approach for this? I could convert the entire section from hex to binary, and iterate through it, but it just seems like a lot of work especially since some sections are super long.
Thanks so much in advance!

Comment: I would probably just use the [`bitarray`](https://github.com/ilanschnell/bitarray) library, instead of rolling my own solution. It has a `from_bytes` method too. So just load the elf file into a `bitarray` and then you can use it like a list.

Comment: This look very similar. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45220959/python-how-do-i-extract-specific-bits-from-a-byte/45221136

Comment: Also read about bitwise operator. https://wiki.python.org/moin/BitwiseOperators

Comment: @Dmitry I looked into bit operators, and got a wired error ```section_bytes >> 5 & 4``` I meant for it to be get 4 bits starting at the fifth bit. And the output is  ```unsupported operand type(s) for >>: 'bytes' and 'int'``` I'm confused by this error

Comment: @Rachel. What type has section_bytes?

Comment: It was byte typed, but I figured it out by using two loops. Thanks a lot though!